# How to connect access database ".accdb" with php

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

I am try to connect access DB with PHP by using this code-

```
$file = FILE_PATH."/SRWOSystem.accdb";
try{
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb , *.accdb)};Dbq=$file");
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

How we resolve that.please help

Comment: This is a genuine issue, why are you giving negative marking?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13473149/625144